# can't run genymotion plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, genymotion

I receive error
    Exception (VBoxManage): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program       Files\Genymobile/reg": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
when I try to run genymotion eclipse plugin. What is wrong? I am using x64 windows 8.1

Answer (score 11):

You will need to set the **correct** path to Genymotion installation directory on eclipse.

The default path on windows is `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`

Have a look at Genymotion eclipse plugin guide: 
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse8

Answer (score 2):

Change the folder name, run again the launcher in eclipse and select the real folder, in my case "C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion"

Comment: This is the right answer for me. Change the folder in Eclipse --> Window --> Preferences --> Genymobile --> Genymotion --> "C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is space in "C:\Program Files\Genymobile". I would try to use "C:\Progra~1\Genymobile/reg" path if it can be configured. Another option is to move to location w/o space in path.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error.

I was getting the wrong folder, its not only .../Genymobile . Its is ...Genymobile/Genymotion

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I didn't [first download and install Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download). I just installed the plugin from the Eclipse installation window and expected it to work. Dumb me.

Answer (score 0):

I was get the same error. The directory of genymotion is
`C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion/reg`
not `C:\Program Files\Genymobile/reg`.

You can copy all files from `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\` to `C:\Program Files\Genymobile`

Then it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this error is caused by invalid path to Genymotion, but **actually it is caused by a bug that does not let Genymotion plugin work with VirtualBox later than 4.2**

To fix this error all you need to do is go here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2
and download the 4.2 version of VirtualBox for your OS. Once you reinstall it - the error is gone and Genymotion plugin opens device list properly

Comment: Installed 4.2.32, still same issue. Have any idea?