# Genymotion Invalid path: VBoxManage and Initialize Engine: failed

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

I use:

- Windows 7
- Android Studio 1.3.2
- Genymotion 2.5.4
- VirtualBox 5.0.4r

Yesterday, it run correctly. However my C disk is run out of space so i decided to uninstall Andriod Studio, Genymotion and VB. Now I installed it in disk E and i show problem

> Genymotion: Genymotion directory: E:\Program
>   Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
>
> Genymotion: Trying to initialize engine
>
> Genymotion: Invalid path: VBoxManage
>
> Genymotion: Initialize Engine: failed

I already tried some solutions from same topic but not work so far, seem like my case is different. Any one have same issue? Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Can you run virtual device from Genymotion? 
If so, is it visible as device after clicking 'Run' button?

Comment: Please also see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31680688/1671597

Comment: Installed 4.2.32, still same error message for me.

Comment: @PawełGrześ I can run virtual device from Genymotion. Also looked your link but still not work. I tried to install VB 4.2.32 but still the same.

Comment: @Richard I hope you got this fixed and squared away.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows 10 here, same issue, added the VirtualBox binary directory to the system path and it still failed, so it's not obvious what exactly it's looking for. But I do have Android Studio in a non-standard location too -- I think it's likely that there's a hardcoded relative path in there that's cracking on use. May not be a fix except to reinstall Android Studio where it wants to go...

However, per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054014/android-studio-genymotion-issues), if you can start the image in Genymotion the Debug button will be able to see it and connect to it and you can maybe live without the integrated Genymotion device manager until they fix this.

Comment: I think the same way like you. I install both Android and VB back to C disk but problem still the same

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file "reg.exe"(in X:\Genymotion) lose, you must get it from genymotion-2.5.3-vbox.exe

Comment: This was the solution for me. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724476/eroor-lunching-genymotion-invalid-path-vboxmanage?lq=1 too.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, and while searching I come across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102944/cant-run-genymotion-plugin-in-eclipse) that says the plugin (at least for eclipse) doesn't work with Virtual Box version newer than 4.2. I am not sure if this will help but it is worth looking in to.

EDIT:: There was an update to Android Studio to 1.4 and an update to the Genymotion plugin to 1.0.6. It fixes this issue. I updated yesterday and it works like a charm.