# EROOR Lunching Genymotion "Invalid path: VBoxManage"

Tags: android, genymotion

When trying to lunch Genymotion in Android-Studio the following error appear:
I have already find this [genymotion-invalid-path-vboxmanage-and-initialize-engine-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669808/genymotion-invalid-path-vboxmanage-and-initialize-engine-failed) but this doesn't solve my issue.

```
20:34:29 Genymotion: Loading Genymotion library
20:34:29 Genymotion: Genymotion directory: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
20:34:29 Genymotion: Trying to initialize engine
20:34:29 Genymotion: Invalid path: VBoxManage
20:34:29 Genymotion: Initialize Engine: failed
```

Have any one idea about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2.5.4 version of Genymotion is not creating the reg.exe file that the plugin uses to locate the VBoxMange path. The previous version had it.

Comment: +1. This worked for me! I downloaded Genymotion 2.5.3, saved the reg.exe file, installed Genymotion 2.5.4 again, and copied the file there. The plugin now works.

Comment: Link for 2.5.3:

http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.5.3/genymotion-2.5.3-vbox.exe

Comment: The last update of Android Studio and the Genymotion plugin should fix this issue.